# A convert back from the given string into byte/sbyte

Tags: c#, string, byte, converters, sbyte

I have a function which form a string like this

```
public static string formString(sbyte myByte)
{
   try
   {
      var str = string.Empty;
      for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
      {
         if(( (1<<i) & myByte ) == 0)
         {
            str = str + "0";
         }
         else
         {
            str = str + "1";
         }
      }
      return str;
   }
   catch (System.Exception ex)
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

In this way, if I put a sbyte like(9), then the string result will be "10010000"  ,   so here's the question , how can I just convert string "10010000" back to the given sbyte?

Comment: why 9 to 10010000 ?? is there any logic behind it ??

Comment: just wanted to show the sbyte into a string like this which means "0" false, "1" true  in 8 chars;

Comment: why not doing myByte.ToString(), because 10010000 is not equivalent to 9

Comment: it's in reverse so the string is "00001001"    I just wanted to convert it back to 9

Comment: have you tried convert? `Convert.ToInt32("00001001", 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string str = "10010000";
str = (str.TrimEnd('0', '\0'));
sbyte s = Convert.ToSByte(str, 2);
```

First remove all the trailing zeros from string and then convert to sbyte with base 2. It will give you back 9.

Comment: Thanks   I just found the answer, lol ,   also thanks this just works!

Answer (score 1):

You probably know how binary works. They are `2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+...`. So when the string is `10010000`, you can just set the result as `2^0+2^3`. I think your output binary string are in reverse order. The string should be `00001001`, you should put the high bit in front of the string and low bit at the back of string. Because the first bit is 1 so the result add 2^0, and the forth element is 1 so the result should add by 2^3. And then you get the result.

Comment: yes the string is just in reverse, so when I convert back , the string should be "00001001", but I do not know how to convert the "00001001" back to sbyte,   I think sbyte.parse would not help

Comment: 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1

Comment: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 <- This is the bit order of binary digit.

Comment: Because only bit number No. 3 and bit No. 0 is 1, so the result should be 2^0 + 2^3. You can get more information about binary conversion through Google.

Comment: string input = "00001001";
            int res = 0;
            for (int i = input.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (input[i] == '1')
                {
                    res += (int)Math.Pow(2, input.Length - 1 - i);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(res);